# tap line resistor

Tags: kegging

I just got my coffin style keezer all set up. I did the calculations to get a "balanced" system at a normal 12 PSI of pressure. This gave me 7 feet of 1/4" hose. Apparently my math was a little wrong, or something, because it seems like it still comes out a bit fast and can cause a bit of foaming.

From what I can tell, there are the following solutions

1. Run longer line
2. run a "choker" line near the shank
3. Find an inline restrictor

I really don't want to run longer lines, one that actually would be expensive since I have 4 taps, and it is already getting a little cluttered with the length of hosing I have

I could do a choker line, I just need to find the right fittings. I would have to ask if I ran a choker line right before it gets to my tailpiece (which is for 1/4" tubing, but I think with some heat I could make it fit snug) would that cause foaming as it would go from 1/4" down to 3/16 then back up technically for the tail piece which is 1/4?

Lastly, it would be nice to be able to just add an in-line resistor of some sort. Has anyone had any luck with these? Has anyone found them anywhere?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest that inserting anything that reduces the line bore inline would cause the beer to foam from the sudden acceleration of the beer with the smaller diameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are fighting the 1/4" line. It is going to flow the beer way too fast at that psi and distance to ever get a good pour. In my experience, trying to get a system exactly balanced on line length and elevation never seems to result in a good pour.

In my kegerator, I run all taps with 10ft of 3/16 line. Most of my beers are run around 10psi and they pour great. I have had a Hefeweizen on tap at about 18psi and it poured fast, but it wasn't overly foamy.

Comment: I might give the 3/16 line a try, but since there is an elevation, the calculation only gives me 2.5 feet or so to bring me down to 0 PSI at the faucet. 3 feet of 3/16 isn't something that is too expensive to give a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Beer hose is normally 3/16" for short runs. IIRC, tailpieces are also 3/16", but if yours is 1/4" that's not a problem, since it's just before the faucet. Making the hose wider is usually ok - the beer simply moves slower which is good to stop it foaming too much in the glass.

I wouldn't take any of those solutions. I'd swap out all the 1/4" for 3/16". 1/4" line has a restriction of [0.85 psi](https://www.google.no/search?q=1/4%22%20beer%20hose%20restriction&aq=f&oq=1/4%22%20beer%20hose%20restriction&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) per foot, while 3/16" has a restriction of [3 psi](http://www.micromatic.com/direct-draw-draft-beer-system-aid-121.html) per foot, so you will reduce the length required considerably.

See also

- [Keg line balancing](http://beersmith.com/blog/2011/07/14/keg-line-length-balancing-the-science-of-draft-beer/), Beersmith Blog

Comment: That is potentially an option as well, but as it is a coffin style keezer (has the faucets up on top) with the vertical lift and the 3/16" hose, I may be getting close to the length that I have available. I suppose I can do the calculation again and see, but I was hoping a nice easy in-line resistor would do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. With the 3/16" line, you will need less than half the length of hose compared to 1/4".

Comment: You are correct, but the distance from my keg to my tail piece (taking into consideration the vertical lift) is greater than what my calculations show I need. If I put the minimum distance between my kegs and the tail piece, I don't think 12 PSI would be enough to push beer out of the faucet.

Comment: What's the distance from your kegs to the faucet, and the elevation?

Comment: My calculation shows that with elevation, I should only be using about 2.5 feet of. This is about the minimum distance I have from my keg to the tail piece. It may be worth an experiment to see if I can stretch it up to 3 feet and still be fine.

Comment: Why not give the actual elevation so we can check your calculation? I'm pretty sure there's a mistake. From 12 psi, 2.5 feet of 3/16 hose reduces the pressure by 3x2.5 = 7.5 psi, so down to 5.5 psi - that implies your kegs are 11 feet below the taps, which is surely not right?

Comment: According to the BYO article http://byo.com/india-pale-ale/item/164-balancing-your-draft-system-advanced-brewing

Elevation = 3 feet = 3/2 = 1.5 PSI
Shank = 1 PSI
faucet = 2 PSI
------------------
4.5 PSI resistance without the line.
I want to end at 1 PSI at the faucet out so 11 PSI - 4.5 = 6.5 PSI of hose line to ballance

6.5/3 = 2.1 feet of 3/16" hosing. I rounded up to 2.5. That being said, I am guessing the resistance of the shank and faucet are a little over estimated. I think I am going to start with about 4 feet of 3/16" line and cut it down if too much resistance.

Comment: You'll definitely need longer hose - in my experience that these calculations result in a pour that is too vigorous coming out the tap, and IIRC I didn't take 3 psi for the shank/faucet, but added extra hose length for that, and it was still too short.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think  4 ft of 3/16 hose would be a good place to start? That still is almost a foot more than the calculation says even if I don't add the resistance of the shank or faucet.

Comment: 6ft is the usual starting point for 2.4vols.